# Socket.io swift client getting reconnected multiple time automatically

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

I'm using  Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 13.1.0' for my app. I have successfully connected my app with Socket server but the problem is, it is getting reconnected multiple time. As a result, maybe i'm unable to emit anything to the server. Can anyone help me with this?

This is my code:

class SocketIOManager: NSObject {

```
var locationReceiverDelegate: LocationReceiverDelegate?
static let shared = SocketIOManager()
let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "server-url")!, config: [.log(true), .connectParams(["token" : "token-string"])])

var socket : SocketIOClient!


override init() {
    super.init()

    socket = manager.defaultSocket
    self.connectSocket() 
}

func connectSocket() {

    socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
        print("socket connected")
    }

    self.socket.on("connected") { ( dataArray, ack)  in
        print("dataArray",dataArray)
    }

    self.socket.on("error") { (data, ack) in
        print("error-->", data)
    }

    self.socket.on("location::share.error") { (data, ack) in
        print("location::share.error-->", data)
    }


    self.socket.on("location::receive") { (data, ack) in

        print("location::receive-->", data[0])

    }

}

func establishConnection() {
    print("in connect socket")
    socket.connect()
}

func disconnectSocket() {
    socket.disconnect()
    print("in disconnect socket")
}

func updateCurrentLocation(myLocation: CLLocation) {

    print(myLocation.coordinate.latitude)
    print(myLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    print(myLocation.course)


    let data : Dictionary<String,Any> = [
        "latitude": myLocation.coordinate.latitude,
        "longitude": myLocation.coordinate.latitude,
        "angle": myLocation.course
    ]
    let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data)
    print(jsonData)
    let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

    print((String(describing: jsonString!)))
    socket.emit("location::share", "\(String(describing: jsonString!))")

}
```

}

Comment: Please show the code where SocketIOManager is used

Answer (score 1):

```
socket.emit(Your_Key, with: [Your_Data])
```

maybe this is how your server looking for data!! (emit array of your data). check your socket status before emitting data.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use socket.off('event') before calling the on event?